# Storing TRANSPORT_HEADERS to restore them after a few requests

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to find a way to store all the transport headers in a property to restore them after a few validating security requests wchich overwrite the headers.

Currently, I'm trying to save the $axis2:TRANSPORT_HEADERS value in another property of the axis2 scope (because of the java.util.Map support).

```
<property action="set" expression="$axis2:TRANSPORT_HEADERS" name="Original_Headers" scope="axis2"/>
```

An then restoring them:

```
<property action="set" expression="$axis2:Original_Headers" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

But this is not working. It just overwrite the headers with nothing, like removing all of them.

Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that
**$trp**
Prefix used to get the transport headers.

I think you should use something like this instead :

```
<property expression="$trp:user-id" name="user-id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="$trp:country" name="country" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used this but is not the perfect way. I wanted something to restore all of the headers without having to know the names